# AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute 'debug_wrapper'

Tags: python

I switched to python 3.7 recently and a old python project which ive been left with has broken.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./main.py", line 17, in
>   
>       import uvloop   File "/Users/--/--/ui/clientui/target/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvloop/**init**.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from .loop import Loop as __BaseLoop  # NOQA   File "uvloop/includes/stdlib.pxi", line 41, in init uvloop.loop
>   AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute
>   'debug_wrapper'

**requirements.txt**

```
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
jinja2==2.10
tornado==4.5.2
tornado-jinja2==0.2.4
pyhocon==0.3.38
structlog[dev]==17.2.0
ujson==1.35
uvloop==0.9.1
watchdog==0.8.3
async_lru==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removed the `uvloop==0.9.1` from my requirements. I think another requirement had it as a dependency and that brought on the conflict.

After doing that I ran pip install again and saw that `uvloop==0.13.0` had then installed.

So try first of all to remove `uvloop==0.9.1` completely from your requirements.